# Need help in forming the Rotation Matrix in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, scenekit

I am really new to Sprite kit and 3D world. I have 3 Eular angles (x:20, y:40, z:10) from which i can make 3 rotation matrices using SCNMatrix4MakeRotation. Just wanted to know whether i can combine the 3 matrices to a single matrics and perform the same operation which i could do by running 3 matrices one after the other

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

The [`SCNMatrix4Mult`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/1409697-scnmatrix4mult) function allows you to multiply the matrices, which is the operation that concatenates 3D transformations.

Comment: Be aware that switching the order in which you concatenate the transforms changes the resulting transform.

Comment: I have 3 matrices (A along x Axis, B along y axis and C along Z axis). So if i use the function as follows let D = SCNMatrix4mult (A, B) let E= SCNMatrix4mult (D, C). 1. Just wanted to know Whether Matrice E will be equivalent to combining the matrices A,B,C. 2. If i apply the matrix E in which order the rotation will get applied